# display childs without parent

Tags: get-children

The following code displays the parent plus its children on the specific parent - and children-category pages as "filter-buttons". But in this list I do not want to display the parent, (because the parent is already displayed as "ALL"). How can I display list with only the children without the parent?

Thank you for any further help.

```
<?php
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
        $url = get_term_link((int)$category->term_id,'category');
        $categories[$key] = "<pre><a href=\"{$url}\">{$category->name}</a></pre>";
    }
    echo "" . implode("\n",$categories) . "";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe there is also ONE code to display the parent as "ALL" on the first place of the list.  
`<?php if (!empty($parent)) : ?><pre><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ); ?>/category/<?php echo $parent; ?>">Alle</a></pre>
      <?php  else: ?><pre><a href="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl' ); ?>/category/<?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>">Alle</a></pre><?php endif; ?>`